# A matrix derivation problem of simple form

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

How to calculate this matrix derivative:

$\frac{\partial W^TWW^TW}{\partial W}$

W is a matrix.

I would appreciate any helps on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define two new matrices and their differentials.
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= W^TW &\implies &dY = W^TdW + dW^TW \cr
 F &= Y^TY =Y^2 &\implies &dF = Y\,dY + dY\,Y \cr
}$$
Then expand $dF$, vectorize it, and calculate the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dF &= YW^TdW + YdW^TW + dW^TW\,Y  + W^TdW\,Y \cr
{\rm vec}\big(dF\big)
 &= {\rm vec}\Big(YW^TdW + YdW^TW + dW^TW\,Y + W^TdW\,Y\Big) \cr
df
 &= \Big(I\otimes YW^T+Y\otimes W^T\Big)\,dw
  + \Big(W^T\otimes Y+YW^T\otimes I\Big)K\,dw \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}
 &= \Big(I\otimes YW^T+Y\otimes W^T\Big) + \Big(W^T\otimes Y+YW^T\otimes I\Big)K \cr
 &= \Big(I\otimes W^TWW^T+W^TW\otimes W^T\Big) + \Big(W^T\otimes W^TW+W^TWW^T\otimes I\Big)K \cr
}$$
where $K$ is the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the vec-operation.

Comment: thank you so much